# retrieving JTextPane AttributeSet values

Tags: java, swing, attributes, jtextpane

When using the `JTextPane` method `insertIcon()`, the javadoc states *`"...This is represented in the associated document as an attribute of one character of content."`*

How do I retrieve the information about my inserted icons? I have tried `getCharacterAttributes()` which only *`"Fetches the character attributes in effect at the current location of the caret, or null."`*

Does a method exist to find all of the attributes in a selection of text, or at a certain index, not just at the current caret position?

**Edit**
Here is some sample code I pieced together to obtain the filename of an embedded icon.

```
Element root = jTextPane.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
BranchElement current = (BranchElement) root.getElement(0);
if (current != null)
{
    Enumeration children = current.children();
    while (children.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Element child = (Element) children.nextElement();
        if (child.getName().equals("icon"))
        {
            AttributeSet attrSet = child.getAttributes();
            ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon) StyleConstants.getIcon(attrSet);
            System.err.println(icon.getDescription());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Element of the Document to get the attributes:

```
Element root = textComponent.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
```

Once you have the root Element you can get the Elements related to your selected text. Start by finding the Element at your start offset and then keep looping through each Element until you reach the end offset.

Comment: Hey camickr, can you please provide some additional details on the looping of elements. `root.getElementCount()` always returns 1 for me. The class of root is `BranchElement(section)`. So I tried `BranchElement current = null;              if(root.getName().equals("section")){                          current = (BranchElement)root;}Enumeration children =  current.children();` but I think I'm going in a wrong direction

Comment: Use the getElement(..) method. If you need more help post your SSCCE. (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

```
StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument)textComponent.getDocument();
int selStart=textComponent.getSelectionStart();
int selEnd=textComponent.getSelectionEnd();
```

Then use doc.getCharacterElement() method passing start to get first char elem. Then using the elem getEndOffset() you can get the next char element. Check the elem start and end offset to be less then selection end.